# Способ изменить параметр виртуального метода не создавая копию переменной

Tags: c++, шаблоны-проектирования

Есть следующий упрощенный код:

```
class RHS
{
public:
    virtual ~RHS() {}

    virtual void operator()(const std::vector<double>& x, std::vector<double>& f, const double t) = 0;
};


class MyRHS : public RHS
{
public:
    void operator()(const std::vector<double>& x, std::vector<double>& f, const double t) override
    {
        // вычисляем f
    }
};


auto main(int, char* []) -> int
{
    MyRHS rhs{};
    std::vector<double> f(10, 0);
    std::vector<double> x(10, 0);

    std::vector<double> x_changed{x};
    x_changed[4] += 0.1;

    rhs(f, x_changed, 1.0);

    return 0;
}
```

Задача стоит - избавиться от создания копии x.
Есть идея создать view-обёртку, например:

```
    template<typename state>
    class Variation
    {
        using state_t = state;
        using value_t = typename state_t::value_type;

        const state_t& x_;
        const size_t i_{};
        const value_t δ_;

    public:
        Variation(const state_t& x, const size_t i, const value_t δ)
            : x_(x), i_(i), δ_(δ) {}

        const value_t operator[](size_t idx) const
        {
            if (i_ == idx)
                return x_[idx] + δ_;
            else
                return x_[idx];
        }
    };
```

Но как передать её в RHS, **не изменяя класс RHS**.
Может есть еще какие то способы избавиться от копирования в данном случае, не затрагивая сам класс RHS?

Comment: Почему нельзя менять RHS? Без этого решения нет. *"`value_t δ_`"* - класс. :/

Comment: что такое `x` ? где ? Если что : ссылки `const тип & x` не создают копий объекта.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat менять можно. Но очень много кода уже написано. Думал, может малой кровью обойтись, и может какая то хитрость есть.

Comment: @AlexGlebe,  x - переменная, в данном случае контейнер.  Ссылки не создают копий, вы правы. Но при создании x_changed копия создается, хотелось бы от неё избавиться

Comment: Без изменения RHS никак нельзя. А если менять можно, то просто сделать эту обертку параметром.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, плохо использовать греческий алвавит в коде?

Comment: Да. Есть отдельные любители использовать юникод, но это большая экзотика, обычно все пишут на английском. Желательно комментарии тоже.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, странно. По-моему, δ  читабельнее delta. Нет ли статей на эту тему? С аргументами?

Comment: мне давно хотелось использовать греческий алфавит. В коде я его не использую, решил сначала тут по-эспериментировать, будут ли замечания от гуру. Как оказалось, будут

Comment: @hermann.minkowski Про статьи не уверен, но аргументы такие. Знаете ли вы, в какой кодировке у вас код? У нормального человека будет UTF-8. Проверили ли вы современные компиляторы (в первую очередь Clang, GCC, MSVC) на то, что все они такое принимают? А отладчики? Получается ли в отладчике вывести переменную по такому имени? Нормально ли отображается имя в сообщениях об ошибках на разных компиляторах и IDE? В виндовой консоли?

Comment: Ну и вообще, это просто неудобно. Представьте, вот вы читаете подобный код. Захотите найти переменную по коду, и придется гуглить символ, чтобы скопировать его. Это если вы знаете, как символ называется, а то вдруг там закорючка какая.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, про кодировку понял. Спасибо

Comment: *"мне давно хотелось использовать греческий алфавит."* - попробуйте язык APL, такие хотелки быстро отпадут. Для начала наберите на своей клавиатуре `{⍵ /⍨ ~{⍵∨≠\⍵}⍵∊'<>'}`

Comment: @user7860670, согласен, юникод не маленький. Но , т.к. греческий алфавит у меня установлен,  и я им достаточно часто  использую для написания формул, хотелось бы и коде его использовать. Аргументы HolyBlackCat меня, к сожалению :), убедили

Comment: @hermann.minkowski простите, я не очень понимаю, вы пытаетесь избавиться от **копирования** при создании `x_changed`? Тогда зачем вы создаете новый вектор и как вы планируете заполнять его без копирования?

Comment: @mazik7512, я пытаюсь избавиться от создании копии вектора x, если в operator() необходимо передать этот вектор, но с изменением. Например, необходимо вызвать функцию с этим вектором, но с измененным одним элементом, или поменять местами элементы. Класс Variation это решает, и похоже, придется переписать RHS, чтобы он работал и с контейнерами и с Variation.

Comment: @hermann.minkowski ну тогда могу только посоветовать в будущем использовать не контейнеры напрямую, а итераторы *(для единообразия интерфейса)* и тогда можно будет менять контейнеры как угодно.

Comment: @mazik7512, в данном случае итераторы не очень удобны, т.к. функция RHS::operator() пишется в таком виде  f[0] = x[1];  f[1] = x[0] * x[0] + x[1] * x[1] - 1.0; Тут удобнее будет шаблонизировать по типу с оператором "квадратные скобки".

Comment: @hermann.minkowski а что неудобного? с итераторами это будет `*dst = *(begin + 1);` и так далее.

Answer (score 3):

Комментарий, но не помещающийся в комментарий...

```
std::vector<double> x(10, 0);

x += 0.1;
rhs(f, x, 1.0);
x -= 0.1;
```

Сам вектор же функцией не изменяется :)

Comment: ;) а как быть, если надо поменять местами два элемента? Или ревертнуть вектор? Не, похоже, всё таки надо переписывать RHS - сделаю  оператор шаблонным, что бы он обрабатывал всё, что имеет оператор [].  И буду использовать аналог Variation с lambda-параметром. Надеялся вчера, что просто туплю, и есть подходящий паттерн (какой-нибудь аналог Адаптер или Мост...)

Comment: теперь меня больше беспокоит вопрос производительности. От копии то мы избавляемся, но при использовании Variation производительность упала в 2-3 раза., по сравнению с вариантом, где просто создается копия.

Comment: @user7860670 Ну да, конечно, просто copy-paste...

Comment: Если вы хотите делать серьезные изменения, то имеет смысл создавать копию. Все зависит от конкретных параметров. При гигабайтном векторе и обмене двух элементов, понятно, лучше менять туда и обратно. При небольшом векторе проще не заморачиваться... Программирование — наука экспериментальная :), надо исследовать разные варианты и замерять. И смотреть, что важнее — память или время.

Comment: вы правы про эксперименты. Именно поэтому я и решил попробовать избавиться от копирования. И вижу замедление в случае x.size() = 2 (~10%) и в случае x.size() = 251001 (~ в пять раз). Буду исследовать

Answer (score -1):

Если вы пишите свой класс MyClass и вам нельзя менять шапку базового оператора, причем, вы не хотите тратить память на копию вектора, можете сделать так:

```
class MyRHS : public RHS
{ 
std::map<int, double> prepMap;
public:
void prepare(const int indx, const int val){
    prepMap[indx]=val;
}
public:
    void operator()(const std::vector<double>& x, std::vector<double>& f, const double t) override
    {
        for (auto i : prepMap)
            f[i.first]+=i.second;
        // вычисляем f
    }
};
```

Затем вызов:

```
rhs.prepare(4,0.1);
rhs(f, x, 1.0);
```

Да, согласна, что x, всё же будет изменен, так как немного не дописала оператор. Вношу изменения в оператор:

```
    void operator()(const std::vector<double>& x, std::vector<double>& f, const double t) override
    {
        for (auto i : prepMap)
           f[i.first]+=i.second;
        // вычисляем f

        for (auto i : prepMap){
              f[i.first]-=i.second;// меняем x обратно
              prepMap.erase(i); // очистка словаря
         }
    }
```

Реализация похожа на ответ выше, но при этом, юзеру кода не нужно заботиться о том, чтобы потом вычесть именно 0.1, а не 0.5. В большой простыне кода можно сделать ошибки при вычитании.
Насчёт траты памяти не согласна, например:
Вектор x содержит 1 000 000 элементов.
Нужно поменять 3 (10й, 5000ный и 9000ый):

```
rhs.prepare(10,0.1);
rhs.prepare(5000,0.2);
rhs.prepare(9000,0.3);
rhs(f, x, 1.0);
```

Получается словарь из 3х элементов.

Comment: Тут не только нужно будет два вектора, но еще и `std::map`.

Comment: prepMap это то же x_changed, только еще больше памяти займет

Comment: Он состоять будет из одного элемента.